# OpenCV remove background noise and artifacts

Tags: java, image, opencv, image-editing

I have the following image:

[image]

I'm able to grayscale this image with a following OpenCV Java code:

```
public static Mat grayscale(Mat mat) throws IOException {
    Mat gray = new Mat(mat.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    if (mat.channels() == 3) {
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    } else if (mat.channels() == 1) {
        mat.copyTo(gray);
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Invalid image type:" + mat.type());
    }
    return gray;
}
```

Right now I need to remove background noise(scanning artifacts, lines) from this image and leave only the scanned card there. I think I have to use threshold, erode there but unable to do it with OpenCV.

I'm playing with it but the result is awful right now and destroys all of the image:

```
public static Mat clean(Mat srcImage) {
    Core.normalize(srcImage, srcImage, 0, 255, Core.NORM_MINMAX);
    Imgproc.threshold(srcImage, srcImage, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
    //Imgproc.erode(srcImage, srcImage, new Mat());
    Imgproc.dilate(srcImage, srcImage, new Mat(), new Point(0, 0), 1);
    return srcImage;
}
```

Please show how it can be achieved with OpenCV Java.

**UPDATED**

I'm trying to port Python example provided by **janu777** to Java. This is my current code:

```
Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread("test.png");

Mat gray = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(image, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Core.absdiff(gray, new Scalar(255), gray);

double thresh = Imgproc.threshold(gray, gray, 5, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_TOZERO);

Mat kernel1 = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(11, 11));
Mat kernel2 = Mat.ones(3, 3, CvType.CV_8U);

Mat erosion = new Mat();
Imgproc.erode(gray, erosion, kernel2);
Mat dilation = new Mat();
Imgproc.dilate(erosion, dilation, kernel1);
```

Right now I have another result than was provide in the answer:

[image]

I'm unable to find a place where `thresh` parameter should be applied and also I'm not using the iterations parameter for `Imgproc.erode` and `Imgproc.dilate` methods because the method signature in this case also requires additional `Point anchor` parameter which I do not have right now.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Do all the scanned cards have that line in the middle?

Comment: @janu777 some of them can have this line but not all

Comment: Here is my result with steps : (1) [the steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do8Lw.png) (2) [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trney.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following @Silencer comment, I implemented the idea using python and Opencv. Please convert the algorithm to work with java.

**Step 1:** Morphological Operations using an elliptical structuring element.

```
img = cv2.imread("test.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.subtract(255,gray)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,5,255,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
kernel1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(11,11))
kernel2 = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(thresh,kernel2,iterations = 1)
dilation = cv2.dilate(erosion,kernel1,iterations = 7)
```

Result: [image: Morph-op]

**Step 2:** Finding contours

```
im2,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
cv2.drawContours(img,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
```

Result:[image: Bounding Rectangle]

**Step 3:** Rotate image and crop

```
# rotate img
angle = rect[2]
rows,cols = img.shape[0], img.shape[1]
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2,rows/2),angle,1)
img_rot = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(cols,rows))

# rotate bounding box
rect0 = (rect[0], rect[1], 0.0)
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
pts = np.int0(cv2.transform(np.array([box]), M))[0]    
pts[pts < 0] = 0

# crop
img_crop = img_rot[pts[1][1]:pts[0][1], 
                   pts[1][0]:pts[2][0]]
cv2.imshow("finalresult.jpg",img_crop)
```

[image: Rotate and crop]

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to port your example to Java. I have updated my question with the current results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you check the subtract line. Because it should invert the Colors in your image. Why is the value 0.255? Post the result image after this step

Comment: In case of `Core.subtract(gray, new Scalar(255), gray);` the image is completely black.

Comment: The idea of that line is to invert the pixels. You must find a way to do it.

Comment: I guess you can use absdiff for this

Comment: Thanks! Now, after the `Core.absdiff(gray, new Scalar(255), gray);` the gray matrix is inverted. Right now something is wrong with `Imgproc.erode()` because I don't know how and where to apply the `thresh` parameter in Java version of this method.

Comment: You are supposed to erode with kernel2 and dilate with kernel1. Check properly

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't know right now how to translate the following line `erosion = cv2.erode(thresh,kernel1,iterations = 1)` to Java equivalent - `Imgproc.erode(..)` I do not see the place in the cImgproc.erode` where `thresh` parameter can be applied

Comment: sorry I made a small change in the code. You must erode with kernel2 and not kernel1

Comment: Thanks, please see my updated question. The result is pretty close but still not equal.

Comment: How to properly convert it ?

Comment: You must achieve the result by trial and error method. Just follow the python code for verification. I don't know java. Good Luck with your project :)

Comment: Thanks for your help!